# Enviar un header en todos los métodos de $resource (ngResource)

Tags: angularjs

Estoy usando ngResource en Angular para acceder a una API RESTful. Creé una `factory` muy simple para lograr esto.

```
.factory('Bookmark', function($resource){
    return $resource('http://bookmarks-angular.herokuapp.com/api/bookmarks/:id');
})
```

En el controlador utilicé `Bookmark.query`:

```
.controller('MainController', function($scope, Category, Bookmark){
    $scope.name = 'Carl';
    Category.getAll(function(data){
        $scope.categories = data.categories;
        $scope.currentCategory = data.categories[0];
        $scope.bookmarks = Bookmark.query();
    });
})
```

Necesito además usar `Bookmark.save` y `Bookmark.remove`, así como un `token` en el encabezado `Authorization`. Buscando encontré una solución:

```
$resource('url/to/json', {}, {
    get: {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { 'something': 'anything' }
    }
});
```

Sin embargo esto funciona solo para el método `get` y quisiera usarlo para enviar el `token` en cada método del `$resource`. No quiero `sobreescribir` cada método solo para asignar el header. ¿Existe alguna alternativa?

**Actualización**

Viendo los comentarios creo que debo agregar que para generar el `token` utilizo **JWT** (JSON Web Token) que lo genero en el backend y lo pasó al frontend cuando se realiza el login, asignándolo a un campo en el `$sessionStorage`. Por ahora este token no expira, pero por razones de seguridad en un futuro próximo deberá hacerlo. Además la url que se envía para generar el `token` y tal vez algunas otras en el futuro no requieren esta verificación.

Answer (score 1):

Angular introduce el concepto de [interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) para todo lo que tiene que ver con peticiones http. Con estas puedes modificar tanto la petición como la respuesta. En tu caso lo que necesitas es un request interceptor ya que el `token` se enviará en cada petición. `$resource` es sólo una capa de abstracción superior al servicio `$http`.

Esta es la forma más simple de lograrlo.

```
function tokenInterceptor() {
    return {
        'request': function (config) {
            // Tienes que usar un factory o $localStorage para saber cual es el token
            // Aquí estoy asumiendo que usas OAuth
            if (token) {
                config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
            }
            return config;
        }
    };
}

function interceptors($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('tokenInterceptor');
}

interceptors.$inject = ['$httpProvider'];

angular.module('myAppModule')
    .factory('tokenInterceptor', tokenInterceptor)
    .config(interceptors);
```

Creas el interceptor como un factory y lo agregas a tu aplicación usando `$httpProvider`.

**Actualización**

La razón por la que debes usar un interceptor es porque los tokens no duran para siempre, es muy probable que expiren, así que si lo pones en un `run block` o un `config block` esto sólo se ejecutará al principio de tu aplicación y luego dejará de funcionar cuando alcance su fecha de expiración.

Si estás tratando de implementar autenticación OAuth o alguna similar creo que te puede servir echarle una vista a [satelizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer) que es la forma más fácil de integrar autenticación por tokens a angular.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [$http.defaults.headers.common](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#setting-http-headers), se aplicara a todas las solicitudes ajax de tu SPA.

```
module.run(function($http) {
  $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer <token aquí>';
});
```

Comment: Siento que esto resuelve el problema pero deja un **terrible agujero** en la aplicación. Lo mejor sería utilizar un mecanismo más seguro como OAuth en lugar de enviar credenciales o permisos mediante headers.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza OAuth, utiliza tokens que debes obtener del servidor de autenticación y enviar en las solicitudes. No resuelve el problema del secreto.

Comment: Lo "resuelve" porque cada token es generado para validar cada request.

Comment: Que? pides un token para cada request...?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Efectivamente OAuth usa headers también y estos se generan **dependiendo del flujo** que hayas escogido y como lo implementas. Si usas refresh tokens obtienes uno nuevo a partir de uno viejo pero eso es solo si implementas refresh tokens y de acuerdo a tiempo de expiración de cada token.

Comment: El token lo genera el servidor, no el cliente, ¿cierto? En ese lado es más seguro. O quizás lo que yo entiendo de la pregunta es que se usará el mismo token en el encabezado de todos los requests, por lo cual me parece una solución peligrosa.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ... y que dejará de funcionar en cuanto el token expire

Comment: @devconcept pero hasta que expire cualquiera puede aprovecharlo y explotar la información..

Comment: @devconcept al leer nuevamente la pregunta, me parece que el token no viaja desde el navegador sino desde el servidor al comunicarse con la API RESTful. De ser así, toda esta lista de comentarios míos está equivocada.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza quizá deberías poner tu respuesta con los cambios que recomiendas.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Si pero puedes invalidarlo y aun así la contraseña del usuario no se verá comprometida. El usuario simplemente verá que se ha vencido su cuenta y se autenticará nuevamente dejando al atacante impotente. El token se obtiene en el navegador dentro de la aplicación al autenticarse en una url determinada y es válido durante la duración que especifique el propio token. Puedes solicitar uno nuevo en cualquier momento pero el cómo dependera si usas refresh tokens o no. Normalmente solo solicitas uno nuevo cuando esta proximo a expirarse.

Comment: @rnd No obstante la solución que propones no es buena ya que todos los tokens(independiente del modelo de seguridad escogido) no duran para siempre y en angular un run block solo se ejecuta al principio de la aplicación lo cual contradice la propia naturaleza de la seguridad que es la de permitirle al usuario cambiar el mecanismo de acceso(tokens, contraseñas, etc) en cualquier momento(en caso que sospeches que ha sido comprometido, por ejemplo).